# Pointer subtraction, 32-bit ARM, negative distance reported as postive

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, embedded, cortex-a8

When performing subtraction of pointers and the first pointer is less than the second, I'm getting an underflow error with the ARM processor.

Example code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

uint8_t * p_formatted_data_end;
uint8_t   formatted_text_buffer[10240];

static _Bool
Flush_Buffer_No_Checksum(void)
{
    _Bool       system_failure_occurred = false;
    p_formatted_data_end = 0; // For demonstration puposes.
    const signed int  length =
        p_formatted_data_end - &formatted_text_buffer[0];
    if (length < 0)
    {
        system_failure_occurred = true;
    }
    //...
    return true;
}
```

The assembly code generated by the IAR compiler is:

```
    807          static _Bool
    808          Flush_Buffer_No_Checksum(void)
    809          {
   \                     Flush_Buffer_No_Checksum:
   \   00000000   0xE92D4070         PUSH     {R4-R6,LR}
   \   00000004   0xE24DD008         SUB      SP,SP,#+8
    810             _Bool       system_failure_occurred = false;
   \   00000008   0xE3A04000         MOV      R4,#+0
    811             p_formatted_data_end = 0; // For demonstration purposes.
   \   0000000C   0xE3A00000         MOV      R0,#+0
   \   00000010   0x........         LDR      R1,??DataTable3_7
   \   00000014   0xE5810000         STR      R0,[R1, #+0]
    812              const signed int  length =
    813                 p_formatted_data_end - &formatted_text_buffer[0];
   \   00000018   0x........         LDR      R0,??DataTable3_7
   \   0000001C   0xE5900000         LDR      R0,[R0, #+0]
   \   00000020   0x........         LDR      R1,??DataTable7_7
   \   00000024   0xE0505001         SUBS     R5,R0,R1
    814             if (length < 0)
   \   00000028   0xE3550000         CMP      R5,#+0
   \   0000002C   0x5A000009         BPL      ??Flush_Buffer_No_Checksum_0
    815              {
    816                  system_failure_occurred = true;
   \   00000030   0xE3A00001         MOV      R0,#+1
   \   00000034   0xE1B04000         MOVS     R4,R0
```

The subtraction instruction `SUBS R5,R0,R1` is equivalent to:

```
R5 = R0 - R1
```

The `N` bit in the `CPSR` register will be set if the result is negative.
*Ref: Section A4.1.106 SUB of [ARM Architecture Reference Manual](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/~waldroj/3d1/arm_arm.pdf)*

Let:

```
R0 == 0x00000000
R1 == 0x802AC6A5
```

Register `R5` will have the value `0x7FD5395C`.
The `N` bit of the `CPSR` register is 0, **indicating the result is not negative**.

The Windows 7 Calculator application is reporting negative, but only when expressed as 64-bits: `FFFFFFFF7FD5395C`.

As an experiment, I used the `ptrdiff_t` type for the length, and the same assembly language was generated.

**Questions:**

1. Is this valid behavior, to have the result of pointer subtraction to
   underflow?
2. What is the recommended data type to view the distance as negative?

**Platform:**
Target Processor: ARM Cortex A8 (TI AM3358)
Compiler: IAR 7.40
Development platform: Windows 7.

Comment: `p_formatted_data_end = 0;` is obviously not pointing to anywhere within the array `formatted_text_buffer` (or the byte after). Pointer arithmetic on unrelated entities is *undefined behaviour*. Note that the sign bit in a processor flags register reflects the ms bit of a register or operation regardless of whether you consider the value to unsigned or signed.

Comment: But isn't a negative result quite feasible anyway? If you subtract the pointer to `formatted_text_buffer[3]` from the pointer to `formatted_text_buffer[0]` (8-bit array) the resulting `-3` tells you how many elements apart they are.

Comment: Arithemtic between two pointers not pointing to the same array is UB.

Comment: you are taking a negative number, and subtracting it from zero and getting a positive number.   Which is correct, what is the problem with that?  0 - (-5) = +5.  Elementary school math.  Now what do you mean by underflow?  This math neither produces an unsigned overflow (C), signed overflow (V), N is zero as you pointed out, and Z is zero.

Comment: Now why you would be doing pointer math on such numbers anyway is another question, and the resulting answer is not something I would point with.  Certainly not if you are doing math with those two addresses...

Comment: None of this is remotely related to ARM, it is simple math.

Comment: @old_timer:  Where did I specify that the pointer values were negative?  My understanding is that pointer values are unsigned in order to access the entire range.

Comment: In bold print you commented on the number being not negative.  If you subtract a number with the sign bit on from a number with the sign bit off it is a positive minus a negative which is a positive plus a positive, so long as you dont go above the half way point the sign bit will be off. Why did you put that text in bold print?  And what is your definition of underflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this valid behavior, to have the result of pointer subtraction to underflow?

Yes, because the behavior in your case is undefined.  *Any* behavior is valid there.  As was observed in comments, the difference between two pointers is defined only for pointers that point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object (C2011, 6.5.6/9).

> What is the recommended data type to view the distance as negative?

Where it is defined, the result of subtracting two pointers is specified to be of type `ptrdiff_t`, a signed integer type of implementation-defined size.  If you evaluate `p1 - p2`, where `p1` points to an array element and `p2` points to a later element of the same array, then the result will be a negative number representable as a `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: As I was discussing this with a colleague, there are not enough bits.  If I have a huge array, then I would need 32-bits for the absolute difference and an additional bit for the sign.  The IAR compiler is only using 32 bits for its ptrdiff_t type, which is not enough.  Because of the use of 32 bits, the maximum array size would be 31 bits to reserve one bit for the sign (when using 32 bits for the ptrdiff_t type).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, either `ptrdiff_t` has enough bits to represent the results of all pointer difference operations ***whose behavior is defined***, or the implementation is non-conforming.  In practice, (conforming) implementations choose a size for `ptrdiff_t` in view of the largest array size they support.  If your implementation in fact does not conform then we don't have any basis for answering the question; otherwise, the answer I've given applies.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Or, looking at it another way, the standard also specifies that "If the result [of a pointer difference] is not representable in an object of [type `ptrdiff_t`], the behavior is undefined."  If `ptrdiff_t` is not wide enough to represent all pointer differences that otherwise would have defined behavior, that serves to make some of those differences undefined.  Where that applies, there's no reason to suppose that there is any way to get the difference as a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is UB as stated in the other answer, most C implementations will simply subtract these pointers anyway `ptrdiff_t` size (or possibly using appropriate arithmetic for their word size  which might also be different if both operands are `near`/`far`/`huge` pointers). The result should fit inside [`ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t), which is usually a [typedef-ed `int`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0004a/c166_lib_ptrdiff_t.htm) on ARM:

```
typedef int ptrdiff_t;
```

So the issue with your code in this particular case will simply be that you are treating an `unsigned int` value as signed, and it doesn't fit. As specified in your question, the address of `formatted_text_buffer` is `0x802AC6A5`, which fits inside `unsigned int`, but `(int)0x802AC6A5` in two's complement form is actually a *negative* number (`-0x7FD5395B`). So subtracting a negative number from `0` will return a positive `int` as expected.

Signed 32-bit integer subtraction will work correctly if both operands are less than `0x7FFFFFFF` apart, and it's reasonable to expect your arrays to be smaller than that:

```
// this will work
const int length = &formatted_text_buffer[0] - &formatted_text_buffer[100];
```

Or, if you really need to do subtract pointers which don't fit into signed 32-bit ints, use `long long` instead:

```
// ...but I doubt you really want this
const long long length = (long long)p_formatted_data_end - 
     (long long)&formatted_text_buffer[0];
```